# Is std::mt19937_64 faster than std::mt19937?

Tags: c++, random

Does `mt19937_64` have a higher throughput (bit/s) than the 32 bit version, `mt19937`, assuming a 64 bit architecture?

What about after vectorization?

Comment: Here are performance comparisons of the PRNG implementations that ship with boost - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random/performance.html

Comment: Have you tried it, or anything?

Comment: Based on the Boost benchmark and in terms of bits per second, mt19937_64 appears to be twice as slow as mt19937. However a basic benchmark suggests that mt19937_64 is actually twice the speed of mt19937.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @byjoe points out, this obviously depends on the compiler.

In this case, it seems to be considerably *more* dependent on the compiler than is typical though. For example, the Boost test linked in the comments uses the compiler from VC++ 2010, and shows only a fairly slight increase in random bits per second from using mt19937_64.

To get more up-to-date information, I whipped up a simple test:

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <class T, class U>
U test(char const *label, U count) {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    T gen(100);

    U result = 0;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (U i = 0; i < count; i++)
        result ^= gen();
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time for " << std::left << std::setw(12) << label
        << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << "\n";
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long long limit = 1000000000;

    auto result1 = test<std::mt19937>("mt19937: ", limit);
    auto result2 = test<std::mt19937_64>("mt19937_64: ", limit);

    std::cout << "Ignore: " << result1 << ", " << result2 << "\n";
}
```

With VC++ 2015 udpate 3 (with /o2b2 /GL, though it probably doesn't matter), I got results like these:

```
Time for mt19937:    4339
Time for mt19937_64: 4215
Ignore: 2598366015, 13977046647333287932
```

This shows mt19937_64 as being slightly faster per call, so over twice as fast per bit as mt19937. With MinGW (using -O3), the results were much more like those linked from the Boost site:

```
Time for mt19937:    2211
Time for mt19937_64: 4183
Ignore: 2598366015, 13977046647333287932
```

In this case, mt19937_64 takes just a little less than twice the time per call, so it's only slightly faster per bit. The highest overall speed seems to be from g++ with mt19937_64, but the difference between g++ and VC++ (on these runs) is less than 1%, so I'm not sure it's reproducible.

For what it's worth, the difference in speed (per call) between mt19937 and mt19937_64 with VC++ is also pretty small, but does seem to be reproducible--it happened quite consistently in my testing. I did wonder about whether that might be (at least partially) a matter of clock management--that when the code first started, the CPU was idle, and the clock had been slowed, so the first part of the first run was at a lower clock speed. To check, I reversed the order to test mt19937_64 first. I think my hypothesis was at least partially correct--when I reversed the order, mt19937_64 slowed down compared to mt19937, so they were nearly identical on a per-call basis with VC++.

Comment: I benchmarked with GCC 4.8.2 (x86_64) on Windows Subsystem for Linux using -O2 and obtained data for 60 trials, each computing 1e9 random numbers on an i7-3820. the average time to completion was 3.576s with mt19937 being negligibly faster (<1%). This puts mt19937_64 as twice as fast.

I suspect that the Boost results were with a 32 bit compiler. As most MinGW builds are x86 as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

It clearly depends on your compiler and their implementation. I just tested and the 64bit version takes about 60% longer call-for-call, so that makes the 64bit version about 25% fast bit-for-bit. I tested with an i7 cpu.

If you need max speed, you may want to consider using something else. Especially if the numbers don't need to be very high quality.

Comment: Actually, mersenne twister appears to be pretty fast, see e.g http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators or http://www.cacert.at/cgi-bin/rngresults That is at least fast compared to what you are going to use the random numbers for.